# if my current date is 31 or 30, then current date is set as highest date than end date why?

Tags: angular, user-interface, frontend

I have working for the datepicker if my current date is 31 or 30 at that time it is set as the highest date than end date,

for other dates it working properly. what would be the issue?

```
    const currentDate = UtilsService.formatDateDDMMYYYY(UtilsService.convertToDateIfMomentObject(new Date()));
    const endDate =  UtilsService.formatDateDDMMYYYY(UtilsService.convertToDateIfMomentObject(event.endDate));


if (endDate) {
            
            if ((currentDate > endDate) || (currentDate == endDate)) {
                this.toastr.error("EOP Date must be greater than current Date",'',TOASTR_TIMEOUT);
                this.dateRangeProductionController.setValue('');
            }
        }
```

```
 <mat-form-field class="daterangepicker sopEopPicker">
                    <div class="projectDtaeRangePicker">
                    <input matInput id="project-sop-eop" autocomplete="off" ngxDaterangepickerMd [showCancel]="true" [locale]="{
                                      displayFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY', separator: ' to '                                           
                                      }" formControlName="dateRangeProductionController" startKey="start"
                        endKey="end" [showDropdowns]="true" [linkedCalendars]="false" placeholder="From  DD/MM/YYYY  to  DD/MM/YYYY"
                        (datesUpdated)="applyClicked($event)" class="form-control" />
                    <label for="project-sop-eop" class="date-range-picker-icon fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></label>
                    </div>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the values of `currentDate` and `endDate`? Does your conversion work correctly?
Sidenote: Why are those functions part of a `UtilsService`? They are stateless, only depend on the input arguments and should be basically e.g. in a `utils.ts` file as exported functions.

Comment: Going strictly based on the names of the functions, it looks like you are casting the dates into a string. Then comparing the strings. So it's comparing them alphabetically instead of numerically.

Comment: But for the date 31 or 30 means that time only it takes current date as highest date, if i choose other date as current date it is working properly. what would be the issue @philipphutterer

Comment: But for the date 31 or 30 means that time only it takes current date as highest date, if i choose other date as current date it is working properly. what would be the issue @dj11223344